# Status bar and navbar color won't change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-styles

I want to change color of navbar and status bar in Android 5 Lolipop app.

Here are my manifest sdk settings:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"
          android:targetSdkVersion="21"
          android:maxSdkVersion="21" />
```

I have this in my my_style.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/navbar</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/navbar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

If I change `android:colorPrimary` color of bar (not status bar/navbar) also changes on layout in IDE and when debugging Android app, but `statusBarColor` and `navigationBarColor` doesn't do anything (https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html - here you can see that it should). I even tried to do:

```
getWindow.setStatusBarColor(Integer.parseInt("00FF00", 16))
```

but it also doesn't work. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved that by adding flag ( Scala code ):

```
getWindow.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
```

before

```
setContentView(R.layout.main)
```

it works in app, but still layout editor doesn't show changes of `android:statusBarColor` and `android:navigationBarColor` items in `app_style.xml`

Comment: How did you get `getWindow` working? For me it says cannot resolve symbol `getWindow`?

Comment: getWindow is in Scala, in Java you probably want getWindow()